# How to find a power of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices

Let $$ B = \begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0\\1&1&0&0\\0&0&0&-1\\0&0&-1&0\end{bmatrix} $$ How to find the following matrix $B^{2023}$?

---

I have tried to diagonalize it, and have found the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, but as I get a product of three $4 \times 4$ matrices, I thought there might be an easier solution. Also how can I prove that $C = A B A^{T}$ is symmetric, where $A$ is a $4 \times 4$ orthogonal matrix (i.e., $A A^T = 1$)?

Comment: Hint: Block matrix

Comment: @BobDobbs what exactly does that mean?

Comment: You could find the first few powers, then guess a general form and prove it by induction.

Comment: @themathfan https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BlockMatrix.html

Comment: @BobDobbs is the way that I've done wrong or it can be considered a solution too?

Comment: @themathfan It is not wrong but long way.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3956303/339790)

Answer (score 4):

Let

$$B=\left[\begin{matrix}X&Y\\Z & T\end{matrix}\right]$$

where

$$X=\left[\begin{matrix}1&1\\1 & 1\end{matrix}\right], \qquad Y=Z=\left[\begin{matrix}0&0\\0 & 0\end{matrix}\right], \qquad T= \left[\begin{matrix}0&-1\\-1 & 0\end{matrix}\right]$$

Since $T^2=I$, we have $T^{2023}=T$ and since $X^2=2X$ we have $X^{2023}=2^{2022}X$. Now, by block matrix multiplication,

$$B^{2023}=\left[\begin{matrix}X^{2023}&O\\O & T^{2023}\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}2^{2022}&2^{2022}&0&0\\2^{2022}&2^{2022}&0&0\\0&0&0&-1\\0&0&-1&0\end{matrix}\right].$$

Comment: thanks a lot! And what about the symmetry of C? Can you give me some hints?

Comment: You can use `\begin{bmatrix}` instead of `\left[\begin{matrix}`

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your second question, which is how to show that $C$ is symmetric, note that \begin{alignat*}{2}
C^T &= \left(ABA^T\right)^T \\
&= AB^TA^T && \text{since } (ABC)^T = C^TB^TA^T\\
&= A BA^T && \text{since $B$ is symmetric} \\
&= C.
\end{alignat*}

Comment: got it, thanks a lot!

Comment: I just noticed, I needed to prove that $$C^{2023}$$ is symmetric, if C is symmetric, can I state that $$C^{2023}$$ is also symmetric?

Comment: @themathfan $\left(C^n\right)^T = \left(C^T\right)^n$, so yes.